# Which effects to fix in SEM with two time points?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am trying to fit a (to me relatively complex) SEM where I'm interested in two dependent variables measured at t2 and assume that this is explained through independent variables at t1. I have never worked properly with time series data so I am unsure on (1) which variables to fix and (2) how to do that in SEMs. I'm using lavaan in R.

Here is my current code:

```
my_reg <-"
# factors / latent variables t1
t1_ls =~ t1_ls_food + t1_ls_livingstandard + t1_ls_finance
t2_ls =~ t2_ls_food + t2_ls_livingstandard + t2_ls_finance
# direct paths
t1_innosum ~ t1_hhincome_log + t1_age + t1_religion + t1_school_ever + t1_lifesatisfaction + gender
t1_school_ever ~ gender + t1_age + t1_religion
t1_hhincome_log ~ t1_age + t1_religion + t1_school_ever
t2_ls ~ t1_innosum + gender + t1_age + t1_school_ever + t1_religion + t1_hhincome_log + a*t1_ls
t2_innosum ~ t1_ls + t1_age + t1_school_ever + t1_religion + t1_hhincome_log + gender + a*t1_innosum
# residuals
t1_ls ~~ t2_ls
t1_innosum ~~ t2_innosum
"

fit_sem <- lavaan::sem(my_reg, data=analysis, ordered=c("t1_x3"))
summary(fit_sem, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

The variables I am mainly interested in as outcomes are "t2_ls" and "t2_innosum".

Dependent variable "ls" is a latent measurement of three other variables, but I would also have a direct measure if this is helpful for model specification (sociological theory suggests differently). As you can see I have only fixed the dependent variables at time point 1 when explaining the respective variables at time point 2, but I am almost certain that I am missing something.

[image: Path diagram]

Is this approach half-way correct and how can I improve this to better reflect the lagged structure of the data?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's less effort to answer this sort of question if you include a path diagram.

Comment: Apologies - point well taken. I have added a picture of the SEM carrying the actual covariate names, which I have also edited in the code.

Comment: Your model and syntax is very hard to parse (at least for me). You have variables called t1 that don't have a t2 (e.g. age). It looks like t2_innosum is an indicator of t1_ls, but t1_innosum is a cause of t2_ls. Gender predicts t2_ls, but not t1_ls. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jeremy Miles, your model is rather complex. As a result, there are a lot of potential issues that could cause problems such as model misfit (e.g., the fact that your exogeneous Time-1 variables don't seem to be allowed to correlate in your path diagram and that you are not accounting for shared indicator-specific variance for the same latent variable indicators across time). I would break it down and start with simpler versions of this model that do not include as many variables at once. For example, you could test the latent autoregressive model for the ls latent variable first/separately as well as the path model with all Time 1 variables. Later on, you can put everything together. That way, it will be easier to parse which effects you may be missing in your complete model.